# How to show View relatively on the image while zoom in/out the image?Footprint: Indoor Positioning with Core Location

Tags: ios, zooming, indoor-positioning-system, footprint

I am using apple's [Footprint: Indoor Positioning with Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014457-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)
I have successfuly implemented it in my iOS application with my custom Floor Plan Image.

now what I want is to zoom in and out this image and i want that my current location pin object on the image should scale according to that and there is no documentation they provide on how to zoom in/out the image of floor plan with the object showing on that image(e.g. user current location pin).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the newer version of Footprint (v2.0): https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html

with:
-Added Swift support -Built-in diagnostic visualizations & annotations for detecting coordinates alignment problems -Uses PDF for better support at multiple device sizes and zoom levels -Uses MKMapView for better rotation and zoom support, as well as native blue dot support -Shows how to handle venue specific regions